# White Space Around Resized Image

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I'm trying to Resize Image by preserving aspect ratio.But there is this white space surrounding the resized image.

```
extension NSImage {
func resizeTo(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
    let ratioX = width / size.width
    let ratioY = height / size.height
    let ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY
    let newHeight = size.height * ratio
    let newWidth = size.width * ratio
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))
    let img = NSImage(size: canvasSize)
    img.lockFocus()
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()
    context?.imageInterpolation = .high
    draw(in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: NSSize(width: newWidth,height: newHeight)), from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size) , operation: .copy, fraction: 1)
    img.unlockFocus()
    return img
    }
}
```

[image]

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First you are picking the smallest ratio from `ratioX` and `ratioY`, but later you create canvas using `ratioX` (of size `width`, `height * ratioX`). I'd say you need to create canvas using `newWidth` and `newHeight`.

```
let canvasSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
```

Additionally, be aware that this script will resize in both directions, i.e. will increase the size of small images.

Comment: If you mean improving code to not increase the size of image, just add check for ratio: `if (ratio) > 0 ratio = 1;`

Comment: so I do this like `var ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY
    if (ratio) > 0
    {
        ratio = 1
    }
`

Comment: This causes some problem .

Comment: Can't help without detailed description.